# Material UI Installing Peer Dependencies

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed the instructions on the material ui website about how to install it. I had a successful installation, but the installation generated several warnings all starting with "npm WARN" and telling me I have to install peer dependencies myself. I'm hoping someone can let me know 1) what is the cause of this issue and 2) how to install the peer dependencies (assuming that's the solution).

Here's everything the terminal displayed after I ran the command to install material-ui

```
PS C:\Users\Benjamin\PROGRAMMING_PROJECTS\REACT_PROJECTS\tutorial_material_ui> npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.15.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @emotion/react@11.4.1
+ @emotion/styled@11.3.0
+ @mui/material@5.0.0
added 36 packages from 46 contributors and audited 1988 packages in 31.331s

155 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: Try running it with the save flag like this -` npm install --save @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

Comment: will that install the peer dependencies?

Comment: yeahh. Also, I meant --saved-dev. so `npm install --save-dev <packg name>`

Comment: That didn't fix the issue